# While ведет себя не так, как ожидаю

Tags: java, libgdx

Все с LibGdx в рендере

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) { // прикоснулся к экрану
    while (bullet.y < 500) {
        bullet.x -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        bullet.y += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
}
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии пуля летела с постоянным ускорением куда-то. С `while` она мгновенно оказывается в 500 по y. Если удалить условия

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    while (bullet.y < 500) {
```

, то пуля летит постоянно и так, как нужно. Если удалить только `while`, то она смещается на заданное расстояние. Я не могу понять, почему из-за `while` она так себя ведет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Игры работают в жизненном цикле. Не знаю как в либгдх, но в целом обычно есть методы вроде update, вызывающиеся за один кадр. так вот если ты за один кадр в update или подобном методе вызываешь while, то он за один кадр выполнится полностью и ты получишь перемещенную мгновенно пулю в данном случае. Пиши просто

```
if (bullet.y < 500)
```

и все должно быть хорошо.
Так же вероятно потребуется переписать условие if (Gdx.input.justTouched()), не проверяя его каждый кадр. Можно завести какой-либо флаг, например isBulletGone, который показывает, что в данный момент пуля летит, именно этот флаг следует устанавливать в true при нажатии. Логика использования может различаться в зависимости от нужной тебе, но в любом случае управление состояниями объектов потребуется.

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
  isBulletGone = true;
}

if (isBulletGone && bullet.y < 500) {
  bullet.x -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
  bullet.y += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
} else {
  isBulletGone = false;
}
```

Возможно лучше было бы сделать bullet участником жизненного цикла, который просто летит, пока выполняется условие, после чего уничтожается.